# Can you explain the Output?

Tags: c++, c

What should be the output of the following code and why? I am little bit confused.

```
int a =10;
printf("%d %d %d",a,a=a+10,a);
```

Comment: Last I checked, the order in which function parameters are evaluated is undefined, so the output here is likewise undefined.

Comment: @Stefano : I don't care about reputation. It's my 2nd day here in stack overflow and I am here because I had a question. A2Z

Comment: I see Neil's doing his famous "Bowl of Petunias" impersonation again :-)

Answer (score 20):

The output is indeterminate, because `a=a+10` is a side-effect, and the compiler is free to evaluate it before or after any of the other parameters.

EDIT: As David points out, the behaviour is actually *undefined*, which means all bets are off and you should never write such code. In practice, the compiler will almost always do something plausible and unpredictable, maybe even differing between debug and optimised builds. I don't think a sperm whale is a likely outcome. Petunias? Perhaps.

Comment: Actually, the behavior is undefined, which means that anything the system does (including turning into a sperm whale and a bowl of petunias) is completely in accordance with the Standard.

Comment: Actually Marcelo, We found a bug in our system which was exactly like that. A side effect in an argument. When in debug everything was fine, but when we started to release, demons started flying out of everyones noses. Bloody UB.

Answer (score 11):

> The order of evaluation for a, b, and c in a function call `f(a,b,c)` is unspecified.

Read about sequence points to get a better idea: (The undefined behavior in this particular case is not due to sequence points. Thanks to @stusmith for pointing that out)

> A [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in imperative programming defines any point in a computer program's execution at which it is guaranteed that all side effects of previous evaluations will have been performed, and no side effects from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed. They are often mentioned in reference to C and C++, because the result of some expressions can depend on the order of evaluation of their subexpressions. Adding one or more sequence points is one method of ensuring a consistent result, because this restricts the possible orders of evaluation.
>
> Sequence points also come into play when the same variable is modified more than once. An often-cited example is the expression `i=i++`, which both assigns `i` to itself and increments `i`; what is the final value of `i`? Language definitions might specify one of the possible behaviors or simply say the behavior is undefined. In C and C++, evaluating such an expression yields **undefined behavior**.

Comment: And specifically for this example, the comma does not define a sequence point. This is so that compilers are free to execute function arguments in whatever order they choose, in order to produce the most effecient code.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the answers.... :)
The behavior is really undefined and compiler dependent. Here are some outputs

Compiled with Turbo c :
20 20 10

Compiled with Visual Studio c++:
20 20 20

Compiled with CC:
20 20 20

Compiled with gcc:
20 20 20

Compiled with dev c++:
20 20 10

Comment: Just wondering: who really cares about the results ? It is **undefined** behavior anyway !

Comment: @ereOn its not about the result: its for verifying that different compilers indeed behave differently instead of blindly believing the answers.

Comment: @Amarghosh: Even if all tested compilers produced the same results, it would *not* mean that the answers are wrong: it is just one of the infinite possibilities induced by an **undefined** behavior ;)

Comment: @ereOn I wasn't suggesting anything towards that. I was just encouraging his attitude: he could have very well thought "oh, it's UB" and stopped there - which is perfectly fine too; but he cared enough to explore it further. I consider that to be a good attitude for a programmer.

Comment: @ereOn:  However, since there were different results, that's at least a strong suggestion that the behavior is implementation-defined, unspecified, or undefined.

Comment: @Amarghosh:  However, experimentation on compilers in order to deduce the Standard, and what can be relied on, is not a good thing to do.  Experiment if you like, but pay attention to the language definition.

Comment: @David I agree that "experimentation on compilers in order to deduce the Standard" is indeed not a good thing to do; I was just complementing the curiosity.

Comment: @Amarghosh: My comment was directed to the answer, not your comment. The sentence "The behavior is **really** undefined" can be misleading for some people, because it suggests what David Thornley warned you about.
I however agree that testing things is a good attitude for a programmer.

Answer (score 4):

Not defined.
The evaluation order of a function parameters is not defined by the standard.
So the output of this could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

using Mingw Compiler in Bloodshed Dev C++ :  20 20 10

Answer (score 2):

Not to amend previous correct answers, but a little additional information: according to the Standard, even this would be undefined:

```
int a =10;
printf("%d %d %d", a = 20, a = 20, a = 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is **highly compiler dependent**.

Because evaluation order of arguments is not specified by standard.